# factorización LU en python

Tags: python, matrices, maxima

He programado un algoritmo en el que A = LU siendo L una matriz triangular inferior y con U siendo una matriz triangular superior con 1 en la diagonal.
He traducido el código de máxima (tipo fortran/matlab) a python, pero no funciona.
El código en maxima:

```
LUcrout(A) := block(
    [n: length(A), L, U],

    /*init*/
    L: zeromatrix(n,n),
    U: zeromatrix(n,n),

    /*algorithm*/
    for j:1 while (j <= n) do(
        U[j][j] : 1,

        for i:j while (i <= n) do(
            L[i][j] : A[i][j] - sum(L[i][k]*U[k][j], k, 1, j-1)
        ),
        for i:j+1 while (i <= n) do(
            U[j][i] : 1/L[j][j] * (A[j][i] - sum(L[j][k] * U[k][i], k, 1, j-1))
        )

    ),

    /*return*/
    [L,U]

)$
```

Mi código en python es el siguiente:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0],[1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1],[0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0],[1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 5],[0, 3, 0, 0, -5, -5, 0],[0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, -5],[0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 0]])
u = np.zeros((7, 7))
l = np.zeros((7, 7))
lik_ukj = 0
ljk_uki = 0

for j in range (0,6):
    u[j][j] = 1
    for i in range (j,6):
        for k in range (0,j-1):
            lik_ukj += l[i][k]*u[k][j]
        l[i][j] = a[i][j] - lik_ukj

    for i in range (j+1,6):
        for k in range (0,j-1):
            ljk_uki += l[j][k]*u[k][i]
        u[j][i] = (1/l[j][j])*(a[j][i]-ljk_uki)

print(a)
print(l)
print(u)
```

y el erro es que en algún punto lii se hace 0 y claro, no se puede dividir entre 0, sin embargo, no debería.
Aquí la traza del error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/home/brian/Escritorio/Uni/FC2/crout2.py", line 18
    u[j][i] = (1/l[j][j])*(a[j][i]-ljk_uki)
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/home/brian/Escritorio/Uni/FC2/crout2.py", line 18
    u[j][i] = (1/l[j][j])*(a[j][i]-ljk_uki)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/home/brian/Escritorio/Uni/FC2/crout2.py", line 17
    ljk_uki += l[j][k]*u[k][i]
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
```

Alguien sabe donde está mi error?
Gracias!

Comment: ponle un `try/except` o un `if`

Comment: lo que pasa es que en principio, con el código en maxima sale el resultado sin problemas, básicamente no debería hacerse o lii